# How can I find whether there is oxygen present inside a well of diameter 1 m at 50 m's deep?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

How can one find whether or not there is enough oxygen for breathing present inside a (dry) well of diameter 1 m at a depth of 50 m?

Many people in Nepal are killed while cleaning wells because of a lack of oxygen.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to ask if there is free oxygen for breathing present deep in a dry well, right?

Comment: If this is for an actual application, please use whatever answer you get as a starting point for a consultation with an expert on such matters.

Comment: is this a theoretical problem or practical one, the data seems as if it is for theoretical purpose.

Comment: Dangle a candle into the well and observe whether it goes out at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

The ideal solution would be a single gas personal detector, such as [this one](http://catalog.enmet.com/compare/l-detector-for-co-h-sub-2-sub-s-o-sub-2-sub-or-l-2/l-detector-for-co-h-sub-2-sub-s-o-sub-2-sub-or-lel?forward=1&itemids=1002+1003+1004+1005+) (it's only the first example I found, I don't know this brand, but there are many equivalent apparatuses from other vendors).

While digital personal detectors are expensive ($200+ range), there are simpler systems which also provide some basic safety (better than nothing). The [Davy lamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_lamp) is perhaps the best known example of these, and it was a huge breakthrough in mine safety when it was popularized after 1815.

[image: Davy lamp]
(Source: http://lindal-in-furness.co.uk/MinersLamps/MinersLamp.jpg)

Comment: The Davy lamp isn't an oxygen detector (or wasn't *designed* to be). It is designed to prevent the lamp flame from igniting flammable gasses that are often present in mines. If the lamp goes out it *is* a sign there isn't enough oxygen, but you would probably already be unconscious at that point so use as a *detector* of low oxygen is a little futile.